# What is the best approach in swift for json data in swift

Tags: swift

What is the best approach in swift for json data.....to save it in a file or coredata..... I want to show prayer times in my app and also show ialamic calendar what is the best approach for saving this type of data

Comment: What do you mean by "best approach for json"? Do you have a fixed JSON file or you get it from a webservice?

Comment: Not fixed json file... Getting it from a webservice but i want only one time download all data and save it.... And then show...

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you'll get 'prayer times' they must be up-to-date. You must fetch the json data from an API  on each app launch. So don't use CoreData or file (don't save it locally), just fetch and fill your Table/Collection View with your data.
You can use a singleton Data service class for fetch operation.

Comment: Basically i am making a calendar app... That will show islamic calendar as well as georgian calendar + prayer times + events..... Can u guide me....i want that just calling one time api and storing all dates and prayer time even when there is no internet connection then the app should show data.....

Comment: Use CoreData then, not file.